# How to change my homepage

Tags: php, url, web

I have an image hosting script written with PHP, but I want to make when people go to [www.taligh.com](http://www.taligh.com) they are redirected to [www.taligh.com/browse](http://www.taligh.com/browse) but the url shouldn't change as in the /browse still shoudn't be added to the utl like the way imgur did it own when you go to imgur.com it takes you to uploaded images instead of landing page any suggestion please?

Comment: Be careful using the word redirect, as many will read that as a HTTP redirect.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make redirect. It all depends on what you want/what seems best for your SEO.

HTML redirect would be (add on the top of http://taligh.com page):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://taligh.com/browse'"/>
```

JavaScript redirect (add on top of the index page, as well):

```
<script>
    window.location = "http://taligh.com/browse";
</script>
```

Apache (if you are using it, ofc):

-Edit .htaccess file, add:

```
Redirect 301 / http://taligh.com/browse
```

Edit: I just realized that you don't want URL to change. You can do that by making index.php file empty and just add `include 'browse.php'` (browse.php is location of your /browse page). This should render your browse page in your home page without changing URL.

Edit: I passed by your code really quick and I think you should change these lines like I did:

```
if(substr($url, strlen($url)-1, 1) == '/')
{
    $filePath = SITE_TEMPLATES_PATH.'/'.$url.'browse.html';
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I did exactly as you told but it didn't work the index.php at the directory root i emptied it and added include 'browse.php' but it didn't work i don't know what's going on.

Comment: @MubaraqIshola It should work. Can you post your directory structure and code for index.php as well your browse?

Comment: I have posted it as an answer please check it out.

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy i have posted it as an answer please check it out.

Comment: @MubaraqIshola I think that the answer would be to change piece of code I put in comment.

Answer (score 0):

one possible way to do this is to put the html code for /browse into what comes up by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a symlink from one file to another.

Or simply require another file from another:

Something like:

Web root's index.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/browse.php';
```

Or could you not just copy browse.php to index.php?